# Plot multiple functions in different intervals (Mathematica)

Tags: function, plot, wolfram-mathematica, intervals

I need some help in Mathematica.
I'm trying to plot functions that are stored in lists like:

list = {{3x,1,5},{2x^2,0,4}}

I need get an output similar to if I inputted:

Show[Plot[3x,{x,1,5}],Plot[2x^2,{x,0,4}]]

But I am not quite sure how this is achieved?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of the many possible ways to do this, here's a perhaps cryptic and terse one-liner, followed by explanation:

```
Show[Plot[#, {x, ##2}] & @@@ list]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

First, `#` is the operator form of [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) and `##` is the operator form of [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html), and `f @@@ expr` is the infix operator for `Apply[f,expr,{1}]]`, so this could be more verbosely expressed as:

```
Show[Apply[Plot[#, {x, ##2}] &, list, {1}]]
```

Thus, for each sub-list of your `list`, the elements are passed as arguments to the pure function. In the pure function, # is the first argument (first sub-element, e.g. the function, `3x`) and `##2` is the rest of the arguments (starting with the second one as a `Sequence`, e.g. `Sequence[0, 4]`). For the first element then, the command evaluated would be `Plot[3x, {x,0,4}]`.

If the above is too cryptic, you could always define a function and use `Map`:

```
plotter[{func_, interval__}] := Plot[func, {x, interval}]
Show[plotter /@ list]
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow absolutely fantastic :D Thank you so much - I've been trying to get my head around this for hours and it turns out to be that simple!

Comment: I always forget about using `SlotSequences`, and this is a very good use of them.

Comment: thanks for nice solution. just to make it complete, to display all plots in different intervals use **PlotRange-> All** `list = {{2 x, 1, 5}, {2 x^2, 0, 4}};
Show[Plot[#, {x, ##2}, PlotRange -> All] & @@@ list]`